What causes the error "unable to confirm transaction" when creating a staking account on mainnet?
I'm following the Solana Validator Documentation, but failing to create a new staking account.
I keep getting the following error:

Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds

I have already checked that I have enough balance in my fee-payer account, so my understanding is that a "transaction expiration" is happening.
Is there anything that I can do to prevent this from happening?
I'm sorry in advance if there is a lack of information here.
I'm new to all this crypto-currency and English is not my first language.
